# How to upgrade Sustainsys.Saml2 from version 0.23.0 to version 2.0.0

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I want to upgrade Sustainsys.Saml2 Nuget package from version 0.23.0 to version 2.0.0.
I have an error in next line of code: spOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;.
The SPOptions class doesn't have a IdentityConfiguration property anymore.

var spOptions = new SPOptions();

spOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;

I want to know how to receive the same behaviour after updating to version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not supported in 2.2 to ignore the audience restriction. I you need that, and still run on the .NET Framework you might as well use 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.